# Table setup for a Squash league. Issues with staff also being players

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening.
I am currently creating a database for a project.

the scenario is as follows:

- A new player can make a compulsory donation after they have
  registered which is accepted by a member of staff.
- A player is separated into divisions based on age as well as gender
  (mixed, women's open, men's open)
- There are two players per match, of which a score is recorded for 3
  sets.
- a staff member acts as an official and umpire for matches, and can
  also be a player across the various divisions

i have normalized the database as best as i can, without pulling my hair out.

i have currently got tables set up as followed:

[image: DB Tables]

The staff and players tables are set up in a one to one relationship, however the assumption is made that a staff member does not have to be a player.

if the staff decide they do not wish to be a player, but remain a staff member, the deletion of the row associated with there player account also deletes the staff account.

if the staff account is deleted it leaves the player account intact.

how can i set this up where a player who is also staff decides he doesn't want to play anymore.

kind regards

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You have players who may or may not be staff. And you have staff who may or may not be players. You should change the relationship between staff and member to: [image]

Comment: thankyou very much for the reply. If this is the case then when i add a staff member, i would also need to store their Name, address etc.. in the staff table instead of the member table? how would i set this relationship up between member and staff. i currently have the StaffID set as a foreign key to MemberID

Comment: Go ahead and add those fields tp the staff table. If you must, you could create a third table called person or user and store thoe things there.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with a junction table Staff_Member. where both StaffID and MemberID were unique and foreign keys to the original tables. if i delete a staff member, it doesnt delete the player, and if i delete the player, it now does not delete the staff member. i think i will make a different table for basic person info and link this up also, as otherwise there will be repeating data for that person and possible mistakes on either side.  Is this the right way to go about it? or is it a "quick" fix that doesnt conform to "theoretical" standards? Kind regards

Comment: It is quite common in databases like this, to sacrifice a bit of normalization in favour of keeping separate tables for staff and users. You will find there are so many separate processes that the difficulty of managing them the same may not be worth it. And if you have a member who is also staff and they change something like their phone number, they may have to change it twice (UPDATE errors) or other normalization issues. But people are used to these types of interactions. So accepting the problem is one possibility.